# Constrain nvarchar columns in entity framework codefirst?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am writing an application that makes use of entity framework.

One of my tables is called `Individuals`, it needs a column `Sex` which should only allow the values `Male`, `Female` or `Unknown`.

How should this be implemented with entity framework? Of course, I can just restrict the input that the user is allowed to enter, but I'd like there to be a constraint on the database also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column should be of type int and then mapped to a field that is an Enum that has the values Unknown, Male, Female.